# Search folder for unread emails in inbox not including subfolders

Tags: outlook

I would like to make a search folder for unread emails in the inbox which does **not** look into subfolders in the inbox. 
Right now I have 5-10 subfolders which are automatically filled with news emails from different sources( using ordinary rules), and then I use the top level of the inbox folder as a kind of **important** email folder. I would like to make a search folder which finds the unread emails in the top level of the inbox folder but **ignores** everything in the subfolders.

Outlook version: 1808 (I think). It is part of MS office 365 but it does run locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Application.AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The `AdvancedSearch` method and related features in the Outlook object model do not create a Search Folder that will appear in the Outlook user interface. However, you can use the [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb206972%28v%3Doffice.12%29) method of the Search object that is returned to create a Search Folder that will appear in the Search Folders list in the Outlook user interface.

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

```
    string scope = "Inbox";
    string filter = "[UnRead] = true";            
    Outlook.Search advancedSearch = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folderInbox = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folderSentMail = null;
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    try
    {
        ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        folderInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        scope = "\'" + folderInbox.FolderPath "\'";
        advancedSearch = OutlookApp.AdvancedSearch(
                                        scope, filter, false, advancedSearchTag );
        advancedSearch.Save();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "An eexception is thrown");
     }
     finally
     {
         if(advancedSearch!=null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(advancedSearch);
         if (folderSentMail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderSentMail);
         if (folderInbox != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderInbox);
         if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but this is too complex for me. I need some pointers on how to use this. I hardly know more than alt+f11 in outlook.

Comment: Never got around to update this. This solution works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In the search box type "Read:unread" without quotes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once located in the folder where you want to search, in the App Outlook Office 365 you can find the filter of unread emails, like this in the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Search Folder to limit the search to only your Inbox in the *Customize* dialog: Click on **Browse...**, then check *Inbox*, and uncheck *Search Subfolders* below the folder tree shown in the dialog window.

Here is the whole process when creating a new Search Folder with your requirements:
Follow steps 1 - 5 under the heading *Create a customized Search folder* here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5.

In step 6, defining your Criteria, click the tab *More Choices*, check the box for *Only items that are:* and select *unread* from the drop-down. Click **OK**.

In the Custom Search Folder dialog, click on **Browse...**, then check *Inbox*, and uncheck *Search Subfolders* below the folder tree shown in the dialog window.

Click **OK** to close the *Select Folder(s)* dialog, then click **OK** to save your Search Folder.